# Conda install of pytorch fails

Tags: pytorch, conda

I created an environment with conda and I want to install pytorch in it, but it doesn't work. After I get inside my environment with `source activate env_name` I tried this: `conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch` (I also tried it like this: `conda install -c pytorch pytorch torchvision`) but I am getting this error:

```
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata: ......
Solving package specifications: ......
Error: Could not find some dependencies for pytorch: mkl >=2018, cudatoolkit >=9.0,<9.1, blas * mkl, cudatoolkit >=10.0,<10.1, cudatoolkit >=9.2,<9.3, blas * openblas, cudnn 7.0.*, cudatoolkit 9.*

Did you mean one of these?

    pytorch, pytorch-gpu, pytorch-cpu

Did you mean one of these?

    cudatoolkit

You can search for this package on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda cudatoolkit 9.*

 (and similarly for the other packages)
```

Here are my installed packages:

```
backports                 1.0                      py34_0  
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size 1.0.0                     <pip>
decorator                 4.0.11                   py34_0  
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                    py34_0  
ipython                   4.2.0                    py34_0  
ipython-genutils          0.1.0                     <pip>
ipython_genutils          0.1.0                    py34_0  
libgfortran               1.0                           0  
numpy                     1.9.2                    py34_0  
openssl                   1.0.2l                        0  
path.py                   10.0                     py34_0  
pexpect                   4.2.1                    py34_0  
pickleshare               0.7.4                    py34_0  
pip                       9.0.1                    py34_1  
ptyprocess                0.5.1                    py34_0  
python                    3.4.5                         0  
readline                  6.2                           2  
scipy                     0.16.0               np19py34_0  
setuptools                27.2.0                   py34_0  
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py34_1  
six                       1.10.0                   py34_0  
sqlite                    3.13.0                        0  
tk                        8.5.18                        0  
traitlets                 4.3.1                    py34_0  
wheel                     0.29.0                   py34_0  
xz                        5.2.3                         0  
zlib                      1.2.11                        0
```

What should I do? Thank you!

Comment: Is there a specific reason for you to keep to such an old Python version?

Comment: @dennlinger I tried to create an environment with a higher version, but other packages are not compatible (such as numpy). I can't change the version from the root directory.

Answer (score 3):

Pytorch's `vision` package (aka `torchvision`) was developed post-Python 3.4, and so only has versions supporting Python 2.7, 3.5-7. Please create a new environment with a later Python version. Note it is always better to include the packages you care about in the creation of the environment, e.g.,

```
conda create -n env_name -c pytorch torchvision
```

and Conda will figure the rest out. If you need to have a specific version of Python, you can include that as well (e.g., `python=3.6`).

Comment: lifesafer, this worked for me even though it didn't work after creating the conda environment! `conda create --name jukebox python=3.7.5 pytorch=1.4 torchvision=0.5 -c pytorch`

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following steps.It worked fine for me.

`source activate env_name
conda install -c pytorch pytorch`

open python shell
`import torch`

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you a definite answer cause you didn't provided the info about the Python version, platform you're using.

Go to the [official website for Pytorch](https://pytorch.org/), choose a installation method according to your platform, Python version and whether you need CUDA.

[image]

Comment: I tried that, too (copying the code provided there), but it still doesn't work. The python version is provided in my post (3.4.5). The cuda version is 10.0 and I run it on a linux.